Treeview.insert give erre res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, *opts)
I am trying to properly insert parent-child relationships in the TreeView. However, I am encountering an error related to the parent index when attempting to insert into the TreeView. These are the relationships I'm trying to insert:



Child
Parent




A1
A


A11
A1


A112
A11


A113
A11


A1121
A112


A11211
A1121


B1
B


B11
B1


B12
B1


B111
B11



This is my code:
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk 
root = tk.Tk()
df2=pd.read_csv('c:/erp/book22.csv')
df_list=list(df2.columns.values)
df_rset=df2.to_numpy().tolist()
df_tree5=ttk.Treeview(root,columns=df_list)
df_tree5.pack()
for i in df_list:
       df_tree5.column(i,width=100,anchor='c')
       df_tree5.heading(i,text=i)
for dt in df_rset:
    v=[r for r in dt]
    df_tree5.insert(v[0],tk.END, text=v[1])
root.mainloop()

And this is my error:
File "c:\mainfol\mfatt\TREEINTREEEVIW.PY", line 16, in <module>
    df_tree5.insert(v[0],tk.END, text=v[1])
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1339, in insert
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, *opts)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Item A not found

 df_tree5.insert(v[0],tk.END, text=v[1])
  File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1339, in insert
    res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, *opts)


You can use a list to store all the item IDs, then check whether the parent of current record is in the list, if not, insert an item as a child of the root item.  Then insert an item for current child:
...

df_tree5 = ttk.Treeview(root, show='tree')
df_tree5.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

parents = []   # list to store all the item IDs
for v in df_rset:
    if v[0] not in parents:
        # current parent does not exist, insert one
        parents.append(df_tree5.insert('', 'end', text=v[0], iid=v[0], open=1))
    # insert current child
    parents.append(df_tree5.insert(v[0], 'end', text=v[1], iid=v[1], open=1))

...

Result:

